# what dictates JSF version? Container or faces-config?

Tags: xml, jsf, jsf-1.2, jboss-eap-4.3.x

I am currently running a legacy JSF application on JBoss AS 4.3.  I believe that this implements JSF 1.2.  However, when I looked at the faces-config, I saw that it was using the JSF 1.1 DTD.

Which version of JSF am I using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exact JSF implementation version information is available in `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file of the JSF implementation JAR file. It's usually located near the bottom of the manifest file as follows:

```
Implementation-Title: Mojarra
Implementation-Version: 1.2_12-b01-FCS
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
```

A JAR file can be opened with a ZIP tool. In case of Sun RI / Mojarra, the filename is `jsf-impl.jar`, sometimes already suffixed with exact version number such as `jsf-impl-1.2_12-b01-FCS.jar`. If you're using the JSF implementation supplied by JBoss 4.3.x, then you can find the file in `$JBOSS_HOME/server/<Profile>/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/jsf-libs` folder. If you supplied your own JSF implementation in `/WEB-INF/lib` and configured `web.xml` to tell JBoss to use it instead, then you need to check it in the one supplied in `/WEB-INF/lib` instead.

Or, you can just get it programmatically:

```java
Package jsfPackage = FacesContext.class.getPackage();
String implTitle = jsfPackage.getImplementationTitle();
String implVersion = jsfPackage.getImplementationVersion();
String implVendor = jsfPackage.getImplementationVendor();
```

As to the `faces-config.xml`, with it you can also control what JSF version the application is designed for. So if you declared it conform JSF 1.1 spec, then even a JSF 1.2/2.0 implementation will run in JSF 1.1 "compatibility modus". But you cannot declare it conform a newer version like JSF 1.2/2.0 when you're *actually* using a JSF 1.1 implementation. It will either error out or be ignored.