# Access JSF and Primefaces version numbers programmatically

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facescontext

I use PrimeFaces 3.5.x and Mojarra JSF 2.1.x
I would like to access and show the versions of both libraries programmatically.

I use the versions as maven2 properties, but I hope there is an easier way to get the versions.
I hope to find something like:

```
Primeface.getVersion();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
```

A JavaScript based solution would be fine too, since I only want to display the version on a status page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329929/1199132):

```java
//returns the major version (2.1)
FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();

//returns the specification version (2.1)
Package.getPackage("com.sun.faces").getSpecificationVersion();

//returns the minor implementation version (2.1.x)
Package.getPackage("com.sun.faces").getImplementationVersion();
```

For Primefaces 3.x you can use the [`Constants`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/util/package-summary.html) class in utils package:

```java
import org.primefaces.util.Constants;

Constants.VERSION
```

Comment: Thanks. For JSF your solution only returns "2.1". To get the minor version as well, I found this: Package.getPackage("com.sun.faces").getImplementationVersion() which returns "2.1.25".

Comment: As mentioned in the answer by @Cagatay this constant was removed in version 4.0 of Primefaces.

Answer (score 17):

In PrimeFaces 4.0, Constants.VERSION is removed in favor of;

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplicationContext().getConfig().getBuildVersion();
```

Also watch out for `FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();`, it doesn't work on some app servers like websphere.

Answer (score 4):

For PrimeFaces, you can use the [Constants](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/util/Constants.html#VERSION) class:

```
org.primefaces.util.Constants.VERSION
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answer by @Cagatay this constant was removed in version 4.0 of Primefaces.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get the Version on runtime, there will not be any instance of RequestContext. Therefore you could use the ImplementationVersion of the package:

```
Package.getPackage("org.primefaces").getImplementationVersion()
```

If the package cannot be resolved, you can try to resolve the version via PrimeFaces class:

```
PrimeFaces.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```