# Getting primefaces version through javascript

Tags: primefaces

Is possible to get Primefaces version using Javascript or Jquery?

According to primeface 4 or newer, widgetVar objects are called through `PF('widgetVar').something()`. While primefaces 3.5 or lower did not support PF function.
Thus, I want to write jquery funtion that support to call widgetVar of dialog through any primefaces version.

Does anyone have any ideas, please share. Thanks.

Comment: The version number can be obtained by [Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18355985/1391249). You can make an AJAX request to fetch it from the server and use in your JavaScript/jQuery code.

Comment: Thanks @Tiny to advise, I think your advise is only one solution to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the PrimeFaces showcase and execute this in the console:

```javascript
PrimeFaces.getFacesResource
```

You would get a hint on how PrimeFaces is getting the current version in Javascript, but unfortunately this function is only available in the showcase script.

So I had to rewrite a similar one.

```javascript
function getPFVersion() {
   var src = $('script[src*="/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js"]').attr("src"); 
   return new RegExp("v=([^&]*)").exec(src)[1];
}
```

---

You can also get the PrimeFaces version in the *backend*:

PrimeFaces 4.0 and higher

```java
String pfVersion = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplicationContext().getConfig().getBuildVersion();
```

PrimeFaces 3.5 and lower

```java
String pfVersion = org.primefaces.util.Constants.VERSION;
```

Comment: Thanks to advise, the second solution, which is PrimeFaces version in the backend is work, better than my solution. Moreover, your javascript is work.

Comment: I found some problem. When I use RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplicationContext().getConfig().getBuildVersion(); with primefaces 3.4.2, NoSuchMethodError exception occur. Thus, this backend proposed is not work with primefaces 3.4.2.

Comment: then you should catch the exception and try this [`org.primefaces.util.Constants.VERSION`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/util/Constants.html#VERSION)

Answer (score 0):

At last, I use resources bundle to store primefaces version which is built by maven.

This snippet code in **Managedbean** to check version and change pattern of jquery calling.

```java
public String getPFPattern(final String widgetVar){
    String sPFVersion = getPrimefacesVersion();
    double iPFVersion = 0;
    String resp = widgetVar;
    if(sPFVersion != null && !sPFVersion.equals("")){
        iPFVersion = Double.parseDouble(sPFVersion);
    }
    if(iPFVersion >= 4){
        resp = "PF('".concat(resp).concat("')");
    }
    return resp;
}

public String getPrimefacesVersion(){
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.xxx");
    return bundle.getString("primefacesVersion");
}
```

My XHTML

```
oncomplete="#{versionBean.getPFPattern('dlgReference')}.show()"
```

The propose method getPFPattern return `PF('xxx')` in case primefaces version 4 or newer