# How to find out the current version of Mojarra which my WebLogic is using?

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra, weblogic12c

I'm trying to identify the current version of Mojarra my WebLogic 12c is using. How can I find out that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way would be to programmatically extract the implementation detail from the [`Package`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html) information of an arbitrary JSF class, such as `FacesContext`.

```
Package p = FacesContext.class.getPackage();
System.out.println(p.getImplementationTitle() + " " + p.getImplementationVersion());
```

Another way would be to explore the JSF module in `/wlserver/modules` folder of WebLogic installation. In my 12c installation, the filename says `glassfish.jsf_1.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar`, which in turn identifies Mojarra 2.1.20.

Comment: Thanks, handy as EL expression too: `#{facesContext.class.package.implementationTitle}:  #{facesContext.class.package.implementationVersion}`

Comment: @Webel: this will fail in EL 2.2 implementations as `class` and `package` are Java literals. You'd need `#{facesContext['class']['package'].implementationXxx}`.

Comment: Both of these work on Mojarra: 2.2.7; Glassfish4.1; [from NetBeans8.1beta;] JDK1.7. `#{facesContext.class.package.implementationTitle}: #{facesContext.class.package.implementationVersion}` and `#{facesContext['class']['package'].implementationXxx}`. For that test the web.xml has web-app version="3.1", where [Servlet 3.1 comes with JSP 2.3 and EL 3.0.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237000/how-can-i-check-what-version-of-el-is-server-using). Q: Are you indicating that the first El expression  `#{facesContext.class.package.implementationXxx}` might not have worked with older EL2.2 ?

Comment: @Webel: Apparently Oracle's EL impl is forgiving in this. Apache EL at least fails on this.

Comment: doesn't identify the full version for me. (only "2.2" of "2.2.6")

Comment: @MarkW: then check WebLogic's module filename.

Comment: @BalusC I did :) that's how I know I'm on 2.2.6 - one with a bean validation bug in I've been trying to solve for days.

Comment: for everyone's ref. I found this (on Jboss) in %Jboss home%\modules\system\layers\base\com\sun\jsf-impl\main

Comment: @MarkW: uh, JBoss is not WebLogic. Current question is about WebLogic. For JBoss head to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329778 and this related one http://stackoverflow.com/q/17085717