# Primefaces p:selectBooleanCheckBox does not show the check mark

Tags: javascript, html, css, primefaces

Primefaces p:selectBooleanCheckBox does not display the Check Mark when clicked. We have for example:

```
<p:dataTable>
....
  <p:column selectionMode="multiple" </p:column>
......
</p:dataTable>
```

What this renders is

```
<TABLE role="grid">
  <THEAD id="displayForm:tblPositionList_head">
  <TR role="row">
   <TH class="ui-state-default ui-selection-column" id="displayForm:tblPositionList:j_idt166" 
   role="columnheader" style="width: 13px; text-align: center;" 
  scope="col"><SPAN class="ui-column-title"></SPAN>
  <DIV class="ui-chkbox ui-chkbox-all ui-widget">
  <DIV class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><INPUT name="displayForm:tblPositionList_checkbox" 
  aria-checked="false" aria-label="Select All" type="checkbox"></DIV>
  <DIV class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><SPAN 
  class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></SPAN></DIV></DIV></TH>
  <TH class="ui-state-default" id="displayForm:tblPositionList:j_idt167" 
  role="columnheader" style="width: 30px;" aria-label="Details" 
  scope="col"><SPAN class="ui-column-title">Details</SPAN></TH>
  <TH class="ui-state-default" id="displayForm:tblPositionList:j_idt169" 
  role="columnheader" style="width: 51px; text-align: center;" aria-label="Edit" 
  scope="col"><SPAN class="ui-column-title">Edit</SPAN></TH>
  <TH class="ui-state-default" id="displayForm:tblPositionList:j_idt170" 
  role="columnheader" style="width: 51px; text-align: center;" aria-label="Delete" 
  scope="col"><SPAN class="ui-column-title">Delete</SPAN></TH>
```

But the above does not show the check mark when clicked. Note however that the functionality works well - which means it really checks and unchecks. Just the display of the check mark is not.

Comment: Are you sure you also didn't update PrimeFaces versions in this migration?  I doubt JBOSS EAP vs WebLogic is causing a CSS issue with PF.  Only a Theme or PF Version would cause a change in behavior.

Comment: Yes. Primefaces 7 is what we used in jboss EAP and in Weblogic. We basically use the same POM.xml except for few mods for Weblogic.

Comment: OK does Weblogic use Mojarra or MyFaces?  could be a difference also.

Comment: I do not have an answer for that. How do I check that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083068/how-to-find-out-the-current-version-of-mojarra-which-my-weblogic-is-using

Comment: @prain99 please remove the weblogic tag, because it is not related.

Answer (score 2):

Check the primefaces theme in the **web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If the theme is set to **none**, then the checkmark will not be shown.

You can use a theme, or replace all

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckBox>
```

with

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckBox>
```

Then the component will be rendered with the default browser style.

Comment: I will check the web.xml.  
Btw, yes we changed the p:select.... to h:select... checkboxes. 
As long as they are outside a p:dataTable it's ok . 
But the multi select p:dataTable checkboxes (like the one shown below)
do not show check mark.                                            
<p:dataTable ...>  
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />                         
</p:dataTable>  
I do not know how to force primefaces to change the checkbox type from p: to h: in p:dataTable components.

Comment: They have changed default `<input type='checkbox'>` to `<div><span 'ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c'/></div>`. You can't change the source code, but you can open an issue. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/new/choose

Comment: This is what we have in our web.xml

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>

Answer (score 1):

Actually the check mark is there but it is **white** on a **white background** - barley visible! I had / wanted to continue using the Boostrap Theme.

Only a CSS style override in my own.css file included in the template could bring the checkbox tick back to black color.

```
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {
    background-image:url("/your/path/resources/images/ui- 
    icons_333333_256x240.png?ln=primefaces-bootstrap&v=10.0.0&e=10.0.0");
 }
 in the template
 <h:head><link href="/reg/css/own.css" rel="stylesheet" /></h:head>
```

Overrides ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png out of the theme.css.